# How do we fast on, so called, "White days" in Zul Hijjah?

Tags: sawm

White days are 13th, 14th and 15th of a lunar month. But in Zul Hijjah it is prohibited to fast on 13th. So the problem is: **How do we fast on, so called, "White days" in Zul Hijjah?**

Should one shift these days -> 14th, 15th and 16th, or how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fast of the white days أيام البيض is basically a specific case of fasting 3 days each months (See for example in [Sahih al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1981)  and the addition of an-Nasa-i in his [Sunan](https://sunnah.com/nasai:2420) adding the white days). As for the later to choice of days is optional, so you may fast them consecutively or separately.

As fasting the days of Tashreeq أيام التشريق  (the three days after 'id al-Adha) without necessity or the specific condition of some of the people performing hajj is strongly discouraged if not regarded as not allowed by the majority of scholars based on the [sahih hadith](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:1997). All fatwas I've found say you first may fast any days except 'Id and the days of tashreeq, due to the fact that white days are only a part of fasting three days each month, may fast any days you like if you want you may fast the 14th, 15th and add the 16th or any other day of the month.

See for example [here](https://binbaz.org.sa/fatwas/12547/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AB-%D8%B9%D8%B4%D8%B1-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%B0%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A9-%D8%A8%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A9-%D8%A7%D9%86%D9%87-%D9%85%D9%86-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B6) -in Arabic- a fatwa of ibn Baaz, [here](https://ar.islamway.net/fatwa/67670/%D8%AD%D9%83%D9%85-%D8%B5%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A3%D9%8A%D8%A7%D9%85-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A8%D9%8A%D8%B6-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%B1-%D8%B0%D9%8A-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%AC%D8%A9-%D9%84%D8%BA%D9%8A%D8%B1-%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AD%D8%A7%D8%AC) a fatwa -in Arabic- of ibn Jabreen and on islamweb fatwa #[57486](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/57486/) -in Arabic-.

Further note that fasting the first nine days of dhil hijja is also recommended.

Comment: Shukran jazeelan! Jazakallahu khairan!